# How to calculate distance points sequentially on the same shapefile?

Tags: qgis

I have a points layer that came from a flight path and I want to calculate the distance between each point sequentially. Ideally I'd need a solution that is do-able inside Graphical Modeler, and doesn't require any extra plugins etc.

I've looked at some of the other answers but nothing has solved this for me.

The flight path loops back on itself multiple times (i.e. it's not a straight line) so I can't use nearest neighbour.

Comment: Are the points ordered somehow, so is there a field that can be used to identify in which order they have to be connected: current point, next one etc.?

Comment: Yes there is an id field called 'fid' that goes from 0-n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the length of the line from each point to the next point, i.e. the point with the `id` that is 1 higher than the current id. Use this expression to do that - in line 7 replace `id` with the name that contains your order-numbers:

```
length (
    make_line (
        $geometry, 
        geometry (
            get_feature_by_id (
                @layer, 
                id+1
            )
        )
    )
)
```

*Screenshot: the red points are connected for visualization purpose with geometry generator and the same expression as above, minus the `length ()` function:*

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked fantastically! For some reason I had to make the layer permanent but otherwise much obliged.

Comment: Strange - worked for me with temporal layer, as you can see on the screenshot. But great to hear that it worked.